# The motion of centre of mass of system only depends on the external forces acting on it but this example seems to be counterintuitive

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The block and monkey have same mass.
The monkey starts climbing up the rope.
After the monkey starts climbing up, the
centre of mass of monkey + block system accelerates/moves with constant velocity in which direction?

after using newtons laws both the block and monkey move with same acceleration upwards, given that the forced applied by the monkey if more than its weight .This means that the centre of mass of the monkey+block system also accelerates upwards, but gravity is the only external force on the system which acts downwards then why is centre of mass of system accelerating upwards

assume pulley to be massless
{given that force applied by monkey on rope is more than its weight}

[image]

Comment: What's keeping the pulley from falling?

Comment: tension which acts in opposite directions

Answer (score 1):

The key to this exercise is to identify all the forces. There is gravity. But the ropes pull the mass and monkey upward.

Think about equal and opposite forces. If the monkey pulls down on the rope, the rope pulls up on the monkey.

Think about the monkey sitting still.

Think about the monkey moving upward at constant velocity. What do you know about the total force on the monkey.

Think about the monkey pulling down on the rope so hard that he accelerates upward.

Comment: but shouldn't the tension forces that pull both monkey and the block act as internal forces for the monkey +block system

Comment: The rope that is holding the pulley up to the ceiling is the external force, which will be more than gravity's.

Comment: thanks now i am clarified

Answer (score 0):

The pulley is exerting force on the monkey/block/rope system. That’s all youre missing.